# Notifying a co worker about an internal job opening you're both qualified for

Tags: communication, politics

I have a co worker I work pretty closely with, we have some overlapping job functions but it has some of the same base qualifications that we cover for the business.

About two years ago, a job opened up, we both applied and he got it. I was promoted a month later to something similar, but nothing changed as far as the work we were responsible for.

So now there is another opening, almost the same as the first job he got the first time. Except this new opportunity is higher up in the company than where we are currently. Since it didn't open inside the facility I don't think he's aware of it. I got some back channel info from another friend in the department that it was coming and saw the posting go up on the website.

but...I feel a bit of internal struggle by not telling my co worker about this opportunity. Maybe he doesn't even want it, but he's certainly qualified for it.

That's my specific story, my question more generally revolves around etiquette, politics, and managing relationships in this scenario.

There is a lot of prevailing wisdom out there about getting ahead sometimes means you put yourself first.

However this feels disingenuous/shady.

Just looking for some perspective, there does not seem to be a lot out there after some GoogleFu.

Comment: Depending of your organization, information can spread fast. From my perspective, I would not like to have a greedy reputation. I would share the information, worst case, he get the job, best case, he is not interested, he give positive feedback of you to others and give you some hints that make you getting the job

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those "do the right thing" situations.

The "right thing" is obvious.  Tell your buddy about it.  If he is better suited for it, it is better for him and better for the company.  The Powers That Preside WILL find out that you told him about it, and, assuming a non-pathological (i.e., non-PHB-dominated) employer, you WILL eventually benefit from the good karma you pile up.

Answer (score 3):

> my question more generally revolves around etiquette, politics, and
>   managing relationships in this scenario.

Unless you have some sort of "pact" with your coworker, you are not compelled to share internal job opening discoveries with anyone.

Certainly your coworker can view the same website that you did and choose to apply (or not).

If you feel that your relationship with this coworker is very valuable, and potentially worth sacrificing the "edge" you may or may not have gained in getting this job, then tell your coworker.

Otherwise, keep it to yourself.

Ultimately, it comes down to how much you value this potential job, how much you value your relationship with this coworker, and your prediction as to how this coworker would feel if you got a job that he didn't learn about. That's something only you can decide.

Comment: One way of testing whether the relationship calls for sharing the information is to think how you would feel if your situations were reversed. Imagine your colleague had found out about the opening, you had not, and he got the job without telling you about it and without you applying. Would you feel that was OK? If so, no need to tell him.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think the workplace might be a right place for such a question but here is framing it in two different contexts, game-theory and interpersonal relations.

---

Game-Theory: With most if not all openings, it is an open competition of many players for one job. Given the constraints, the more players, the more competition. The agency or employer, would seek to find the best fit (in terms of behavior, experience, and skill set for the role).

If you want to increase your chances, ensuring that there are no other viable candidates would be in your interest. Now this isn't an ethics call, but a numerical one. This is of course, presuming that the two of you are equally skilled as a fit for the role. If your coworker > you, then it definitely doesn't make sense.

---

Let's pivot and approach this from an interpersonal perspective. In good team, and I use the word loosely, one celebrates another's accomplishments and seeks out opportunity to help the team accomplish its goals. If an individual within the team accepts employment elsewhere, one views it as a forlorn good bye, not with anger or jealousy that they are leaving.

---

If you tell your coworker, and they are interested, and they get it, you will have lost out in terms of position and $. The tradeoff is that you might've gained a plus in their book. If they come across a open position in their new job, they will more likely return the favor.

If you tell your coworker, and they are interested, and you get it, you will gain in position and $.  The tradeoff is that you might've gained some "resentment and jealousy" (why you and not him/her?) in a 'bad' team environment or "good for you, I'm happy for you" in a 'good' environment.

If you don't tell your coworker, and they are interested, and they find out you applied, it's a toss up. But then again, it is not your job to look out for their interests.

At a certain point the number of permutations of this game gets convoluted and hard to map out through text.

A good question to ask yourself is whether or not you want the role and seek to maximize your chances of getting it or if you value your relationships at the workplace.